# Bug while creating object in View

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm working on a backbone.js project which is mainly to learn backbone framework itself.

However I'm stuck at this problem which i can't figure out but might have an idea about the problem...

I've got an Create View looking like this...

```
define(['backbone', 'underscore', 'jade!templates/addAccount', 'models/accountmodel', 'common/serializeObject'], 
function(Backbone, underscore, template, AccountModel, SerializeObject){
return Backbone.View.extend({
    //Templates
    template: template,
    //Constructor
    initialize: function(){
        this.accCollection = this.options.accCollection; 
    },
    //Events
    events: {
        'submit .add-account-form': 'saveAccount'
    },
    //Event functions
    saveAccount: function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        //Using common/serializeObject function to get a JSON data object from form
        var myObj = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
        console.log("Saving!");
        this.accCollection.create(new AccountModel(myObj), {
            success: function(){
                myObj = null;
                this.close();
                Backbone.history.navigate('accounts', {trigger:true});
            },
            error: function(){
                //show 500?
            }
        });
    },
    //Display functions
    render: function(){
        $('.currentPage').html("<h3>Accounts <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'> </span> New Account</h3>");
        //Render it in jade template  
        this.$el.html(this.template());

        return this;
    }
});

});
```

The problem is that for every single time I visit the create page and go to another and visit it again. It remebers it, it seems. And when i finally create a new account I get that many times I've visited total number of accounts...
So console.log("Saving!"); in saveAccount function is called x times visited page...
Do I have to close/delete current view when leaving it or what is this?

***EDIT***
Here's a part of the route where i init my view..

```
"account/new" : function(){
                var accCollection = new AccountCollection();
                this.nav(new CreateAccountView({el:'.content', accCollection:accCollection}));
                console.log("new account");
           },
```

/Regards

Comment: Edited the question, check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have zombie views. Every time you do this:

```
new CreateAccountView({el:'.content', accCollection:accCollection})
```

you're attaching an event listener to `.content` but nothing seems to be detaching it. The usual approach is to call [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) on a view to remove it from the DOM and tell it to clean up after itself. The default `remove` does things you don't want it to:

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
}
```

You don't want that `this.$el.remove()` call since your view is not responsible for creating its own `el`, you probably want:

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.empty();        // Remove the content we added.
  this.undelegateEvents(); // Unbind your event handler.
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
}
```

Then your router can keep track of the currently open view and `remove` it before throwing up another one with things like this:

```
if(this.currentView)
    this.currentView.remove();
this.currentView = new CreateAccountView({ ... });
this.nav(this.currentView);
```

---

While I'm here, your code will break as soon as you upgrade your Backbone. As of [version 1.1](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> - Backbone Views no longer automatically attach options passed to the constructor as `this.options`, but you can do it yourself if you prefer.

So your `initialize`:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.accCollection = this.options.accCollection; 
},
```

won't work in 1.1+. However, some options are automatically copied:

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName`, `attributes` and `events`.

so you could toss out your `initialize`, refer to `this.collection` instead of `this.accCollection` inside the view, and instantiate the view using:

```
new CreateAccountView({el: '.content', collection: accCollection})
```

Comment: You rock! Thanks for the well explained answer. Cheers